# Lumen Login always return Unauthorized

Tags: php, session, authentication, lumen

Log in using the correct user name and password,but redirect to '/',always return  'Unauthorized' .what should i do?

`routes.php`

```
$app->get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthenticationController@getLogin');
$app->post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthenticationController@login');
$app->post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthenticationController@register');

$app->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('/', 'ExampleController@index');
});
```

Comment: Because 'GET' method to root '/' is under middleware.

Comment: i have post my email and password, should redirect to '/',,but return 'Unauthorized'.

Comment: post the code what you have got in middleware auth

Comment: public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Ran your screenshot through OCR. Please just paste the code directly next time!